# NullPointer Exception with @BeforeClass but not with @BeforeMethod using Selenium with Java and TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, testng

I'm changing test and it turns out that it will be better to split it into three separate tests.

I've created setup method that should be run before whole class.

When I'm using @BeforeMethod with one huge test everything is ok, but when I change this into 3 tests and @BeforeClass I'm getting this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.framework.ui.driver.lifecycle.SingleUseDriverLifecycle.getWebDriver(SingleUseDriverLifecycle.java:36)
   at com.framework.ui.UITestLifecycle.getWebDriver(UITestLifecycle.java:149)
   at com.framework.ui.pages.BasePage.<init>(BasePage.java:32)
   at adminPanel.pages.LoginAP.<init>(LoginAP.java:19)
```

Browser starts for a second and it's closed very fast.

[image]

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: can you share your code for better understanding?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials including `@BeforeClass`, `@BeforeMethod` and `@Test`

Comment: @swapyonubuntu Now I know more, I'm limited by the internal company framework. All tests need to extend class BaseUITest, where @Before/After Methods have "alwaysRun = true", and they will close browser and create new driver and open new browser. @Before/After Class is not supported. This is absurd but i have to work with it. Do you see any work around? BaseUITest is read only.

Comment: In many frameworks, only in BeforeMethod, driver object would be initialized. Since you are trying to something in BeforeClass, you may be getting this error. Either avoid using BeforeClass altogether or initialize browser in BeforeClass before doing any action.